# Nature of equation of line $sz+t\bar z+r=0$, s,t and r are complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $s,t,r$ be non-zero complex numbers and $L$ be the set of solutions $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R \}$ and $i=\sqrt{-1}$ of the equation :

$$sz+t\bar z+r=0$$

where $\bar z=x-iy$ prove that it has exactly one element then  $|s|\ne |t|$.

I have prove it using
$s=a+ib$, $t=c+id$ and $r=e+if$

Using the equation $sz+t\bar z+r=0$, we get two line equation

(a+c)x+(d-b)y+e=0

(b+d)x+(a-c)y+f=0

For unique solution we have $a^2+b^2 \ne c^2+d^2$ viz.$|s|\ne |t|$(neglecting the negative value)

Can I prove it without using the substituion as outlined above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as
\begin{cases}
sz+t\bar{z}=-r \\[4px]
\bar{t}z+\bar{s}\bar{z}=-\bar{r}
\end{cases}
Considering $z$ and $\bar{z}$ as independent variables, we know that the system has a unique solution if and only if
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} s & t \\ \bar{t} & \bar{s} \end{bmatrix}=|s|^2-|t|^2\ne0
$$